# What will be the output of -m-- if m = 5 in java?

Tags: java, arrays, numbers, operator-keyword

```
class number {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int m = 5;
        System.out.println(-m--);
    }
}
```

When I execute the code it prints output as m = -5 ... But how ?? can anyone please explain me this. I am a beginner..

Comment: When you do `System.out.println(-m--);` , this is evaluated to `System.out.println(" "-(m--));.`

Comment: `System.out.println(-m--);` is executed as `int tmp = m; m = m-1; System.out.println(-tmp);` with the difference that in the first case the temporary value is stored on the evaluation stack only whereas in the second case it is stored into a local variable too.